# Should you tell a recruiter what your salary expections are?

Tags: salary, recruitment

When sending a reasonable generic (ie not specific to a particular job) letter to a recruiter, should you mention what your salary expectations are?

Or can this be used against you? - (ie recruiter tells the employer what the low end is).

Comment: @Chad I would argue not a dupe, as it concerns dealing with recruiters, not salary negotiation.

Comment: That is your opening bid in your salary negotiation.  Wether you realize it or not.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Answer (score 2):

> should you mention what your salary expectations are?

If you are contacting an agency who will work on your behalf to help you find a job, then Yes - you need to tell them what salary you would be willing to accept. Otherwise, they will not be able to find jobs that are a good match.

If instead you are contacting a recruiter who is working for a company, but it's not about a particular job, then I assume you just want this recruiter to "keep you in mind". In that case, there probably is no advantage to stating your salary requirements. Wait until a specific job appears, or until you are specifically asked for your salary requirements.